# install node packages without restarting docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

Is there a way to install node packages in a running docker environment without restarting?
I have running a few containers via docker-compose and need to use `npm i <packagename>` while the containers are running.

So far, I have found no consistent answer to google.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any command in an active container using `docker exec`. In your case it will be:

```
// Replace <your-container-id> and <your-package-name>
docker exec -it <your-container-id> "npm install <your-package-name>"
```

**or** if you want to use a **container name** instead of a **container id** you can use:

```
// Replace <your-container-id> and <your-package-name>
docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep <your-container-name> | awk '{ print $1 }') "npm install <your-package-name>"
```

Here you have more informations about the docker exec **[docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)** command. (Docker Docs)

Comment: This doesn't work for me since I get: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"npm install node-red-contrib-env\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Answer (score 0):

```
docker exec -it [container-id] /bin/bash
```

`cd` to the workspace and `npm install packagename` . Should install the package you want and also add it in package.json

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker exec` + `npm install <package-name>`.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/